# How to make a function parameter optional (to avoid calling all parameters each time)

Tags: swift

I want to make a function parameter optional, so when I call the function I don't always have to have all three parameters, eg:

```
func doSomething(name: String, age: String, gender: String?)
```

In that case, I'd want to not always have to specify a gender, so I could call:

```
doSomething(name: "Dave", age: 25, gender: "Male")
```

or leave out the gender and just call:

```
doSomething(name: "Dave", age: 25)
```

But when I do, it tells me it unexpectedly found nil, or that there's a missing parameter, how can I make the 'gender' input optional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just give it a default value.

```
func doSomething(name: String, age: String, gender: String? = "Male")
```

or

```
func doSomething(name: String, age: String, gender: String? = nil)
```

Quoted from [the Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

> You can define a default value for any parameter in a function by assigning a value to the parameter after that parameter’s type. If a default value is defined, you can omit that parameter when calling the function.

**UPDATE**: Please note that declaring a variable that is of an optional type does not mean that you can omit this parameter when calling the function. It just means that this parameter can hold either a value depending on its type, or a `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to do something like the designated initializers pattern, like so:

```
class Person {

    func doSomething(name: String, age: String, gender: String?) {
        // do something with these informations
    }

    func doSomething(name: String, age: String) {
        self.doSomething(name, age: age, gender: nil)
    }

}
```

Then you can ommit the last parameter, as your method calls the designated method in return